# instanceof Pattern matching in Java, not compiling

Tags: java, object, compiler-errors, pattern-matching, instanceof

Below is a paragraph taken from 'Java - The Complete Reference' book, 12th edition.

> ```
> Number myOb = Integer.valueOf(9);
> int count = 10; 
> if((count < 100) && myOb instanceof Integer iObj) { // is OK 
> // myOb is both an Integer and nonnegative, and count is less than 100. 
> iObj = count; 
> //.. 
> }
> ```
>
> This fragment compiles because the if block will execute only when both sides of the && are
>
> true. Thus, the use of iObj in the if block is valid. However, a compilation error will result if
>
> you tried to use the & rather than the &&, as shown here:
>
> ```
> if((count < 100) & myOb instanceof Integer iObj) { // Error!
> ```
>
> In this case, the compiler cannot know whether or not iObj will be in scope in the if block
>
> because the right side of the & will not necessarily be evaluated.

I completely do not understand the last few lines, why would the code even enter the if block if the pattern matching fails, if it succeeds and the first condition is true, then what's wrong with using '&' instead of '&&'.

The code works if I initialise iObj manually inside the if block, but why is pattern matching not doing it? When it's whole idea was to create a reference variable, pointing to the extracted object of mentioned type.

What I get before manual initialization

`Compile Error: iObj may not be initialized`

What I tried

```
if((count < 100) & myOb instanceof Integer iObj) {
int iObj = (Integer) myOb;
}
```

And now it works.

I want to know why, this happens.

I am using JDK 20 in Windows

```
java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: `but why is pattern matching not doing it?` It's new syntax that does the initialization for you.  If you don't have new features available or enabled, you won't be able to compile and run that code.

Comment: I use JDK 17, which has the feature, it's not about enabling or disabling, I believe. It's about using '&' or '&&'. I would want you to try the code out, and let me know if you find anything. Thank you.

Comment: The author of the bock you cite, Herbert Schildt, apparently has [quite a reputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Schildt#Reception) for writing programmings books on various languages that are riddled with errors. For example, [the following has been said](https://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn3e.html) about his C book from the 90:s: _"describing a language subtly but quite definitely different from C"_. Your quote seems to confirm that. It is not only wrong about `&`, it has horrible formatting and fail to use auto-boxing, which as been in the language for 20 years.

Comment: In addition to @Lii’s comment, you should note that even the first example is wrong. The comment says “*myOb is both an Integer and nonnegative*” but the condition did not check whether the value is nonnegative. My guess is that the author copied the example from somewhere else and it originally was `myOb instanceof Integer iObj && iObj >= 0` where everything made sense, the value was guaranteed to be non-negative and it can’t work that way with `&`. Then, he decided to modify the example to create his own, but broke it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the quote explains why the second case does not compile is worded extremely strange, maybe even wrong. So here is my way of explaining it.

The way you have to look at pattern match variables is that they are only declared if they are assigned (in the spec they call this 'introducing' a pattern variable).

Let's look at an example:

```java
if(myOb instanceof Integer iObj) {
    // ...
}
```

Now inside this if statement, the `instanceof` must have returned `true`, so `iObj` is 'introduced' and therefore declared. This means you can both read from it, and write to it (as it isn't a final variable, note that `myOb instanceof final Integer iObj` is valid Java).

Let's now jump to the first case given:

```java
if((count < 100) && myOb instanceof Integer iObj) {
    // ...
}
```

So why does this work? The language designers made sure that if you have a statement in the form of:

```java
if (exprA && exprB) {
  // ...
}
```

that it is equivalent to:

```java
if (exprA) {
  if (exprB) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This why you have short circuiting in Java and so many other languages.
Doing this to the 1st case we get:

```java
if (count < 100) {
  if (myOb instanceof Integer iObj) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Because the inner if matches the first example I gave, it makes sense that again inside the if block the pattern variable must have been 'introduced' and is therefore assignable.

So why doesn't this work with `&` just like with `&&`? Well, because the language designers decided not to I suppose.

I do have an argument as to why they decided this. Given a statement like this:

```java
if (exprA & exprB) {
  // ...
}
```

It is essentially the same as:

```java
boolean tempA = exprA;
boolean tempB = exprB;
if (tempA && tempB) {
  // ...
}
```

And although we can split the `&&` operator here again, it doesn't matter. In the case you gave, we would get `boolean tempB = myOb instanceof Integer iObj`.
This statement can't 'introduce' a pattern variable because it could be that `myOb` wasn't an Integer which means that it can't guarantee that `iObj` would be assigned.

So even though 'myOb instanceof Integer iObj' in both cases must have returned true for the code in the if block to be run, because the language designers didn't make rules for how pattern variables get introduced by `&` like they did with `&&`, the 2nd case in the book won't compile like the first one.

So why can you use `int iObj = ...` in the if block with `&` but not with `&&`?
Well, as we just saw with `&`, the compiler doesn't consider the pattern variable to be 'introduced' to the block, so you can define it inside, but with `&&` that is illegal because the pattern variable IS introduced, which means you can't redeclare it.

Comment: So basically it is because they haven't perfected the feature, and the design for `&` in Java is incomplete for pattern matching?

Comment: @FlavianDiolD I think it's a design decision they made. The way pattern introducing works is quite similar to how definite assignment works (chapter 16 of the java spec). This part of the spec also doesn't have any special casing for `&` like they have for `&&`. But that just changes the question into "why is there no special casing for stuff like `&` in definite assignment analysis?", to which I don't have the answer.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot @Kroppeb

Answer (score 0):

First, the quote as presented in the question is crap!

The `&&` is the "shortcut" form that does not guarantee that both sides will be executed; in this case, if the first term evaluates to `false`, the second one will never be touched. `&` guarantees that both terms are evaluated.

Nevertheless, it is possible that Pattern Matching does not work with single `&` for some reason (but not for that one given in the quote!!)

Pattern matching for `instanceof` was introduced in Java 14 as a preview, a second preview was started in Java 15, until it was finalised in Java 16. And the JEP talks in fact only about `&&` and `||`, not about `&` and `|`. But to have that behaving different than the shortcuts does not make much sense.

Meanwhile, I tried

```
if( (count < 100) & myOb instanceof Integer iObj ) 
{
   int iObj = (Integer) myOb;
}
```

with Java 21, and it works – unexpectedly! But when I use `&&`, it complains about the assignment/declaration in the body, because `iObj` was already declared … strange!!

But the [JLS 6.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1) also talk about the shortcuts only …

Perhaps [JLS 15.22.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2) gives the answer: there `&` and `|` are labeled as "boolean logical operators", while 6.3.1 talked about `&&` and `||` as "Conditional-And" or "Conditional-Or" operators, respectively.

But then the question arises why the dangling `iObj` in the `instanceof` term with the single `&` does not cause a syntax error?

Comment: The `&` in the question is a BITWISE Operation. It is meant to take in 2 values and produce a numeric value. That can work fine with pattern-matching, but requires the OP to use it correctly, and they didn't

Comment: I see your edit. No, it is not a bug. Here, I'll finish up my answer and post.

Comment: It is bitwise operation, but it can be used for `boolean` operations, too. Read the JLS, 15.22.2! Ok, it is bitwise `boolean` …

Comment: I know, but that's my point. `boolean` is a primitive, and that's the problem. Like I said, I am typing up my answer, and I will address this then.

Comment: I'm sorry but I guess you mistook the question, - @tquadrat. "But when I use &&, it complains about the assignment/declaration in the body, because ´iObj` was already declared … strange!!". This is not strange, as the whole idea of pattern matching was not to initialise a variable by seperate typecasting. Kindly refer https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching.html to know more.

Comment: @tquadrat, the quotes is taken from a book which is updated upto JDK 17. So I don't think the issue is with the book being outdated.

Comment: @FlavianDiolD When I said out-of-date, I meant in relation to Java 21. But either way, that's not the main problem. I am still typing up my answer. It is a very lengthy answer.

Comment: @FlavianDiolD – Strange is the behaviour  of the `&` version in comparison to the `&&` variant … obviously it got not fully clear.

Comment: @FlavianDiolD – I never said "outdated", I said "crap". Translate that to wrong! The description on how `&&`/`||` works in comparison to `&`/`|` given there is invalid.

Comment: @tquadrat - I totally understand that the comparison given there is not valid for the usual cases, but I believe that somehow pattern matching seems to be somewhat of an exception. And I want to know why, and your answer solves the error, which I myself did. I want to know why such an illogical error occurs, for I strongly believe that it is not a bug.

Comment: *"with Java 21, and it works – unexpectedly! But when I use &&, it complains about the assignment/declaration in the body, because `iObj` was already declared … strange!!"* I think I have finally figured this out: With `&&` the pattern declares `iObj`, and there are rules in [JLS 6.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1) to propagate the pattern variable to the if-body. Because of this you can't use that name again, so the error is natural.

Comment: But `&` isn't mentioned in JLS 6.3.1. You can still use a pattern with `&`, but the pattern variable `iObj` is not propagated to the if-body. Your can only use the pattern variable in the if-test-expression. Because of this the name `iObj` can be reused to declare another variable in the body. What do you think?

Comment: @Lii – Have you tried that? Something like `if( a instanceof B aB & aB.isValid() ) { …`? I cannot try it myself currently …

Comment: @Lii - I kinda accept your concept, about `iObj` not propagating to the `if` body, if that was really the case, then should we never use `&` while pattern matching. If you know more about this, kindly post it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: JLS 6.3.1 - "Scope for Pattern Variables in Expressions" - states that no scope rules apply to `&` (as opposed to `&&` and `instanceof`) - so in `a instanceof B aB & aB.isValid()`, the sub-expression `a instanceof B aB` is allowed and introduces a Pattern Variable (PV), but since there is no scope rule for `&`, `aB.isValid()` will not compile ("cannot find symbol")

Comment: @user85421 Stole it from my mouth. I am talking to the amber dev team to get the terminology right in my post. But this is the crux of it.

Comment: @tquadrat I tried it right now. user85421 is right: It doesn't work, I was wrong about that. It seems that `a instanceof B b` is allowed but useless together with `&`.

Comment: @user85421 would you mind posting this as an answer with examples and detailed explanation?. Would be a great help. Thank you

Comment: @Lii Again, it's definitely not useless. There's a right way and a wrong way to use it. I almost regret announcing that I was going to write an answer because of how long it has taken me. But I jumped in here so many times because I do not want misinformation to be spread, and the 2 threads on this question have been full of it. Every conversation you all are having has already been had before by the people actually putting pattern-matching in Java. And the book in question is made by someone who talks to the Java team regularly for decades. There are no bugs here - either in the book or Java.

Comment: Though, the book picked a horribly confusing example for beginners. While the book may be correct, it picked a horrifically beginner-unfriendly example that so many people in this thread have understandably mixed themselves up on. I promise, I will post an answer that will get this all explained. I simply refuse to put out something that I am not 100% certain, so I am fact-checking everything before I click post.

Comment: Comment threads are not meant for long discussions, but I enjoy this one... :)  @davidalayachew *"it's definitely not useless"* The thing I think is useless is to combine `a instanceof B b`, and `instanceof` with a pattern that declares a variable, with `&`. There seems to be no point at all to the variable because it it not propagated anywhere, so you can't use it. Logical `&` by itself can be occasionally useful, and `instanceof` that declares a variable is very useful, but not the combination in this example. Or is there something I have missed about `&` and `instanceof`?

Comment: @davidalayachew: *"In this case, the compiler cannot know whether or not iObj will be in scope in the if block because the right side of the & will not necessarily be evaluated."* This statement in the book is clearly wrong. The difference between `&&` and boolean `&` is that both sides of `&` are always evaluated, while for `&&` the right side is only evaluated when the left side is `true`.

Comment: @davidalayachew "*I will post an answer that will get this all explained*". I think you are wrong in some ways but I'm looking forward to your answer and I hope you get some information from the Amber experts. :)

Comment: @Lii I assert all of my original claims, including that the quote you are talking about from the book is correct. But yes, I am open to being wrong, and will admit it if it comes to be false. I will be sure to notify everyone here once I post my answer.